# JNI Crashes when I do anything at all :S

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Java code:

```
package library;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Library
{    
    static{System.loadLibrary("TestDLL");}

    native static void GetGLBuffer(ByteBuffer Buffer, int Width, int Height, int Size);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ByteBuffer B = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(5);
        byte[] C = {'H', 'E', 'R', 'E', '\0'};
        B.put(C);
        GetGLBuffer(B, 0, 0, 4);
        System.out.println((char)B.get(0));
    }
}
```

C++ Code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_library_Library_GetGLBuffer(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject buffer, jint Width, jint Height, jint Size)
{
    unsigned char* Buff = (unsigned char*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(buffer);
    //*Buff = 'A'; Crashes it.
    //Buff[0] = 'A'; Crashes it.
    //std::cout<<Buff[0]; Prints fine but crashes when this function ends.
}
```

If I do nothing, it works perfectly fine. Also, if I declare variables within the function above, it crashes.

How do I fix it? Am I doing anything wrong?

It prints out this file: http://pastebin.com/Mz76Bk8G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to say that I solved it. I had to go into my JNI folder, copy the JNI.h and the JNI_MD.h for JDK 7 to my C++ project folder, include it as a file and also use a .def file to export.

Without doing all of the above steps, it crashed the JVM. Now I'm not sure why but I'm just glad it works. I'm posting this to let others who have the same problem fix it.

Thanx for the views guys. Was quite difficult to figure out what was wrong. Hope this comment helps others.

Comment: You shouldn't copy files; you should #include them from where they already are. You shouldn't need a .def file with JNI.

Comment: Doesn't work without the .def. I have no clue why.

I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library.GetGLBuffer(L
java/nio/ByteBuffer;)V
        at Library.GetGLBuffer(Native Method)
        at Library.main(Library.java:21)

Now if I use the .def file, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not passing an array of bytes into your C function, but rather a ByteBuffer object. To set values inside the buffer, you'll need to call the methods on the buffer object, which from C means querying the object for its class, querying the class for the proper method, then invoking the method.

For example, if you wanted to do the equivalent of calling the put(int index, byte b) method on the ByteBuffer object, you'd need to do something like this in your C code:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, objID);
jmethodId mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "put","(IB)V");
if(mid == 0) return;
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, objID, mid, 0, 'A');
```

Comment: He is using a direct byte buffer; he is calling the correct method to get the direct buffer address; he is then using the direct buffer address directly. His code is correct and should work.

Comment: It's definitely been too long since I've done anything with JNI - totally forgot about using direct byte buffers. Thanks for the correction!